# Is there any way to embed a hyperlink in a RichEmbed?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a link like `[this](https://stackoverflow.com/)`, but I can't seem to find any answers to if this is possible.

I've already tried the markdown syntax (as seen above) but I can't seem to find any other answers.

This is the code I am currently using:

```js
message.author.send({
  embed: new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle("DiscordBot Help")
    .setColor("#42b6f4")
    .addField("help cosmetic - Cosmetic help.", "All cosmetic commands")
    .addField("help economy - Economy help.", "All economy commands")
    .addField("facts - Gives you facts", "Subcommands required")
    .addField("credits - Shows the developers", "All hail the Creators!")
    .addField("info - Fun info about DiscordBot", "10 fun facts.. or what?")
    .addField("patch - Shows current patch/updates.", "UPDATES ARE AWESOME!")
    // This is the line I'm having trouble with.
    .addField("Add DiscordBot to your server! [Click here](https://discordapp.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=439778986050977792&scope=bot&permissions=8)", "Its mine now.")
    // Here the line ends.
    .addField("Enter prefix before the commands", "It wont work else ;)")
    .addField("MIT License | Copyright © 2018, Technotype", "All rights reserved.")
    .addField("More content coming soon!", "It'll just take time")
});
```

I expected the output from the code to be something like this:

```
Add DiscordBot to your server! [Click here](https://discordapp.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=439778986050977792&scope=bot&permissions=8)
```

But instead I got the output:

```
Add DiscordBot to your server! \[Click here\]\(https://discordapp.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=439778986050977792&scope=bot&permissions=8\)
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Field names can't contain links, but field values can.
So something like this  would work:

```
.addField("Its mine now", "Add DiscordBot to your server! [Click here](https://discordapp.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=439778986050977792&scope=bot&permissions=8)")
```